# Comprobar en DJango si se devuelve algún objeto

Tags: python, django

Veran, tengo 2 tablas, una de ellas enlazada con la otra con una relación one-to-one:

```
class animal(models.Model):
    ncomun=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ncientifico=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foto=models.ImageField(upload_to='animal/')
    categoria=models.ForeignKey(categoria,null=True)
    alimentacion=models.ForeignKey(alimentacion,null=True)
    desplazamiento=models.ManyToManyField(desplazamiento, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ncomun

class extra(models.Model):
    texto=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    animal=models.OneToOneField(animal)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.animal.ncomun
```

Lo que intento es que en una vista en la que se mostrara un determinado animal, aparezca tambien su información en la tabla *`extra`*, pero en caso de que un animal no tenga un extra asignado, se muestre un mensaje predeterminado.

```
def datos_animal(request,i):
    try:
        fiera=extra.objects.get(animal=i)
        adicion=fiera.texto
    except fiera.DoesNotExist:
        adicion='El boton Retroceder te lleva a la pagina desde la cual has venido.'
    try:
        ani=animal.objects.get(pk=i)  
    except animal.DoesNotExist:
        ani=None
    return render(request,"indice.html",{"ani":ani,"numero":animal.objects.count(),"adicion":adicion})
```

Sin embargo, me sale este mensaje de error:

> local variable 'fiera' referenced before assignment.

¿Como deberia hacer para que funcione la vista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en tu primer `try-except`, si no se encuentra el objeto en la tabla `extra` la excepción lanzada es `extra.DoesNotExist` no `fiera.DoesNotExist` como estas intentando capturar. Si el try falla `fiera` no existe porque es definida dentro del mismo `try`. El código debería ser algo así:

```
def datos_animal(request,i):
    try:
        adicion=extra.objects.get(animal=i).texto
    except extra.DoesNotExist:
        adicion='El boton Retroceder te lleva a la pagina desde la cual has venido.'
    try:
        ani=animal.objects.get(pk=i)  
    except animal.DoesNotExist:
        ani=None
    return render(request,"indice.html",{"ani":ani,"numero":animal.objects.count(),"adicion":adicion})
```

Comment: ¡Pues muchas gracias! Ha funcionado.